# C++, no matching function for call to 'filter'

Tags: c++, class

I wrote a class called `Matrix`, with the following code which works

```
Matrix Matrix::operator<(int num) const {
    Matrix tmp=*this;
    Between t(1,2);
    return filter(*this,t);
}
```

but why this doesn't compile?

```
Matrix Matrix::operator<(int num) const {
    Matrix tmp=*this;
    return filter(*this,Between(1,2););
}
```

and how to fix this?

```
Matrix filter (const Matrix& int_matrix, Between& field)
```

Comment: `Between&` ⟶ `Between const&`.

Comment: How would you expect this to work? You're using a comparison operator and not even checking the input

Answer (score 1):

`filter` takes the 2nd parameter by lvalue-reference to non-const, which can't bind to temporaries like `Between(1,2)`.

As the workaround you can make `filter` taking parameter by lvalue-reference to const, which could bind to temporary objects.

```
Matrix filter (const Matrix& int_matrix, const Between& field)
```

Or pass-by-value.

```
Matrix filter (const Matrix& int_matrix, Between field)
```

Comment: sorry but I don't get that, why I need to declare it as const, I'm not sending const to it...

Comment: @clark_smith Because we can't bind rvalues to lvalue-reference to non-const. For example we can't do `Between& rb = Between(1,2);` or `int& ri = 0;`.

Comment: @clark_smith That's just the rule. Temporaries cannot be bound to a non-const ref.